# Is a metric space without Cauchy sequences complete?

Tags: functional-analysis

> A metric space $X$ is said to be *complete* if every Cauchy sequence in $X$ has a limit which is an element of $X$.

If a metric space lacks Cauchy sequences, e.g. $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{R}$, is it then complete?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, yes, but in fact the only metric space with no Cauchy sequences is the empty metric space. $\mathbb{N}$ has plenty of Cauchy sequences, for example $1,1,1,1,1,\ldots$ and $1,2,3,4,5,57,57,57,57,57,\ldots$.

Comment: Ooh. At least it's easy to show that they converge. Thanks!